# Inconsistency in Prefork module

Tags: apache2

I have the following situation:

- running `aptitude search apache2-mpm-` gives me :

  ```
  p  ...
  p  ...
  i   apache2-mpm-worker     -transitional worker MPM package for apache2
  p   ...
  ```
- But when I execute `apache2 -V` I get the response

  ```
  server_MPM: prefork
  ```
- furthermore, when executing `apache2 -l`,  `prefork.c` is missing

I am not sure whether there is something wrong in the configuration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three standard MPMs (`prefork`, `worker` and `event`) are available in the `apache2-bin` package (and thus on all `apache2` installations for Apache 2.4):

```
$ dpkg -L apache2-bin | grep mpm    
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
```

From [the changelog entry for `2.4.1-1`](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5/changelog):

```
* Refactor binary packages, now as things simplified. MPMs are simple
  modules now, they can be bundled into the same binary package which do not
  need to conflict with each other. Thus, Apache now primarily consists of the
  following packages:
  + apache2 - configuration files and init scripts, Debian specific helper
  scripts
  + apache2-bin - binaries and modules
  + apache2-data - error pages and images
```

By default, `prefork` is enabled.